# App running on simulator but not on Expo Go

Tags: react-native, expo

I am looking to run the react-native-tesseract-ocr module for a project. I can run the example on my Mac but to use the camera I am trying to run it on the Expo Go app that I have installed on my mobile. This however, is not loading.

On my Mac, I'm using the following commands in the project directory:

```
npx pod-install ios

npx react-native run-ios
```

The Expo Go Quickstart says to run:

```
npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npx expo start
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=quickstart

When I try to install the ocr module, I'm guessing it's not being built correctly for the app to work.

Can somebody point me in the right direction, please?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**react-native-tesseract-ocr** won't work with expo go , because it use native code.

try for this package instead for expo go : https://github.com/wodin/expo-ocr-example